# configure не находит usbutils

Tags: linux, сборка, libusb

Собираю udev для LFS.

```
configure: error: Package requirements (usbutils >= 0.82) were not met:

No package 'usbutils' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables USBUTILS_CFLAGS
and USBUTILS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

root@kali: ~/udev # apt list | grep usbutils
                                                                                                                                                                                                          
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

usbutils/kali-rolling,unstable,unknown,now 1:014-1 amd64 [installed]

root@kali: ~/udev # pkg-config usbutils --libs
Package usbutils was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `usbutils.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'usbutils' found
```

Ну и что делать-то? В гугле только другая проблема - usbutils есть, а команды lsusb нету

Comment: По тому качеству и количеству вопросов, которые вы задаёте последнее время, мне кажется вам какую-то литературу почитать стоит про то как собирают и устанавливают программы из исходников, что такое линковщик и динамическая линковка, а что такое вспомогательные утилиты, типа `pkg-config`. Ах, ну и да, читайте же, что вам пишет программа, там же всё понятно, с чего начинать.

Comment: я просто решил собрать свой дистрибутив. "Концепт" есть, решил реализовать...

Comment: Это похвально! Однако не стоит забывать про домашнюю работу. (Лично я когда-то собирал дистрибутив под один проект на базе OpenWall, правда я уже немного понимал, что к чему при сборке пакетов).